# Как в WPF сделать привязку к CheckBox'у?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Добрый день! Не могу понять как сделать в WPF привязку видимости элемента(Кнопки) к CheckBox'у(видно/не видно), как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Определим конвертер преобразования из `bool` в `Visibility`:

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {  
        return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

дальше в ресурсах объявим созданный конвертер:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

затем биндим свойство `Visibility` нужного нам элемента к свойству `IsChecked` `CheckBox`:

```
<CheckBox Name="checkbox"/>
<Button Content="Button" 
        Visibility="{Binding ElementName=checkbox, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

**UPD** (по совету [Foggy Finder](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/227049/foggy-finder))

Также можно использовать и стандартные конвертеры( полный список можно посмотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12977516/6936696))

Например:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```